Spring Boot 3.3+ and Open Telemetry export to Google Cloud Trace?
I'm trying to get Open Telemetry to export traces from my Spring Boot 3.3.5 application running on GKE.
I've tried follow the guide here which says to use:
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry.instrumentation</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-instrumentation-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

However, I've upgraded to version 2.8.0 (2.10.0 didn't work because of incompatibilities).
I've also added this:
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry.instrumentation</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

I have the following application.yaml in Spring Boot:
otel:
  trace:
    sampler: traceidratio
    traceidratio: 0.1
  propagators:
    - tracecontext
  resource:
    attributes:
      deployment.environment: test
      service:
        name: my-service
        namespace: my-company
  traces:
    exporter: google_cloud_trace

Since I want to export to Google Cloud Trace, I've also tried to follow the Google Open Telemetry documentation here by also depending on:
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.opentelemetry</groupId>
  <artifactId>exporter-auto</artifactId>
  <version>0.33.0-alpha</version>
  <classifier>shaded</classifier>
</dependency>

But when deploying my app to GKE, I get this error in the logs:
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t] 2024-11-19T09:34:19.522Z ERROR 1 --- [my-service] [alhost:4318/...] i.o.exporter.internal.http.HttpExporter  : Failed to export logs. The request could not be executed. Full error message: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:4318
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t] java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:4318
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.kt:297)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:207)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at io.opentelemetry.exporter.sender.okhttp.internal.RetryInterceptor.intercept(RetryInterceptor.java:91)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t] Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Unknown Source)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(Unknown Source)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.kt:128)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.kt:295)
[my-service-55fc6bd6c-bfs5t]    ... 20 common frames omitted

I.e. it seems to me that otel tries to send traces to 127.0.0.1:4318 instead of Google Cloud Trace. I've also tried deploying the application without the exporter-auto library, and instead making use of com.google.cloud.opentelemetry:exporter-trace (see docs here), but I haven't got this to work either (it complains that google_cloud_trace exporter is not found, which is resolved when switching to the exporter-auto).
How can I configure Spring Boot 3.3+ and OTel to export traces to Google Cloud Trace?

if you are using spring boot application in your GKE cluster you can try this:
https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/reference/html/index.html#cloud-trace
also
if you want to go with otel exporter:
try deploy it in GKE cluster: https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/instrumentation/opentelemetry-collector-gke
then configure your java application to send traces to opentelemetry endpoint: OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT="http://opentelemetry-collector.opentelemetry.svc.cluster.local:4317"(By default)
For java application you can configure Java agent to create traces and send it to cloud trace
https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/java/getting-started/
Ideally your env should look something lke this:
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-javaagent:/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar"
OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER=otlp
